# Adding additional attributes to ExtJS5 Grid Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs5

In one of my project there is an aspx grid. I have to replace it with ExtJS5 grid. It has a functionality of right click. For this a third party tool is used. I know we can do that with context menu in ExtJS but the client insist on using the third party context menu. It works like this:

Whenever the grid is created, an attribute *oncontextmenu="recordID=12321"* is added to every row of the grid where 12321 is just a sample. It is defferent for every row.

My requirement is to add this very attribute to every row of the grid. How can we achive that in ExtJS5? The "recordID" is available with the store.

Comment: Can you just add it in your initial query? Have it load the the value from the service for every row and just add the item to your model so it is in your store by default.

Comment: What do you mean by an "attribute" of every "row"? Are you talking about the <tr> element? Some other HTML element? The row's bound record itself?

Comment: I have the record in my store. It need not to be bounded to any grid column. The only thing needed is when the grid is rendered its rows are like <tr class.......>Column Content</tr> What I need is the HTML should become <tr oncontextmenu="recordID=12321".......>Column Content</tr> and it should be for every grid row. RecordID is present in my model and store. I just need it included in every grid row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO easiest way to do this is to change `rowTpl` in view:

```
grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    [...],
    viewConfig: {
        rowTpl: [
            '{%',
                'var dataRowCls = values.recordIndex === -1 ? "" : " ' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-row";',
            '%}',
            '<tr oncontextmenu="recordID={[values.record.get(\'field1\')]}" class="{[values.rowClasses.join(" ")]} {[dataRowCls]}" {rowAttr:attributes} {ariaRowAttr}>',
                '<tpl for="columns">' +
                    '{%',
                        'parent.view.renderCell(values, parent.record, parent.recordIndex, parent.rowIndex, xindex - 1, out, parent)',
                     '%}',
                '</tpl>',
            '</tr>'
        ]
    }
});
```

Alternatively it is possible to set any attribute on `td` in column `renderer` function, but then you need to do it for each column.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/dhw3w81v/1/